# CSS3 box-flex - box size differs depending on inner content

Tags: css

Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong here? I want the boxes to be the EXACT same width between both divA and divB. Just because divB box has slightly longer text in 'p2' should not change the width of the entire box. I don't want to use hard pixel widths for the 'p1' so that it can be flexible for viewport widths. I just want p1 box to always be half the size of p2, regardless of inner content. Can someone help me out or suggest a better method??

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css"> 
div
{
display:-moz-box; /* Firefox */
display:-webkit-box; /* Safari and Chrome */
display:box;
width:100%;
border:1px solid black;
}

#p1
{
-moz-box-flex:1.0; /* Firefox */
-webkit-box-flex:1.0; /* Safari and Chrome */
box-flex:1.0;
text-align:right;
border:1px solid red;
}

#p2
{
-moz-box-flex:2.0; /* Firefox */
-webkit-box-flex:2.0; /* Safari and Chrome */
box-flex:2.0;
text-align:left;
border:1px solid blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='divA'>
<p id="p1">Hello</p>
<p id="p2">Column 2</p>
</div>

<div id='divB'>
<p id="p1">Hello</p>
<p id="p2">Why is this box larger</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you give the children an explicit width, they will behave.
The flex value will override these widths, giving you the desired layout. The boxes just need a value to start from. Without a defined width, they shrink to their content's width, then the flex value is applied.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZBE7r/

```
...
#p1, #p2 {
    width: 1px;
}
...
```

It only works if they all have the same explicit width (can be any value: 0, 1px, 100%, etc)

Comment: sometimes (Firefox 10) works only if I also add min-width: 1px;

Comment: this should be included in any flexbox tutorial. life saver

Answer (score 1):

Found this quote. This might explain why it's doing that.

"That sounds like it's working as expected. The flexing is only applied after the preferred sizes of the boxes have been calculated. So in your example it sounds like the total box width adds up to something far bigger than the container width. The browser then uses to flex property to decide which boxes to squash to make them fit. Your middle box has the most flex so therefore it is squashed the most" [link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/)

Answer (score 0):

If you change the `p` tags to `div` tags it seems to work as expected. It seems the flexbox calculates width by first checking the initial width of the element, and then filling out the remaining space proportionally. Both are block-level elements, so I'm not sure why they are being handled differently, but it should fix your problem.

Comment: thanks Nate but that actually didn't work either. even with divs it did the exact same thing.
.flex
{

display:-webkit-box;
width:300px;
border:1px solid black;
}

#p1
{

-webkit-box-flex:1;
text-align:right;
border:1px solid red;
}

#p2
{
-webkit-box-flex:1; /* Safari and Chrome */
text-align:left;
border:1px solid blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class='flex'>
<div id="p1">Hello</div>
<div id="p2">Column 2</div>
</div>

<div class='flex'>
<div id="p1">Hello</div>
<div id="p2">Why is this box larger</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>